# What is the difference in the latent space of a variational autoencoder and a regular autoencoder?

Tags: latent-variable, autoencoders, embeddings

Should VAEs be even used for non-generative tasks? If I were to use both models for embedding images, how would the embedding space differ on a structural level?

Answer (score 2):

For the vanilla autoencoder the structure is like this:

[image]

It can be treated as a nonlinear extension of PCA, while for the variational autoencoder a mean and a standard deviation is added as a layer for each hidden variable in the middle layer:

[image]

For the detailed difference please refer to [this answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/421660/103153).

> Should VAEs be even used for non-generative tasks?

Yes, you can. The additional KL divergence(between variational distribution and the prior distribution/normal distribution) loss can be just seen a regularization and regularization can reduce the variance(at the risk of increasing bias).

> If I were to use both models for embedding images, how would the embedding space differ on a structural level?

For the VAE the values of embedding would just be like samples from the normal distribution while that doesn't hold for the general autoencoder.

Reference:
[Intuitively Understanding Variational Autoencoders](https://towardsdatascience.com/intuitively-understanding-variational-autoencoders-1bfe67eb5daf)

Comment: Sorry, but this only states what they are. I'm asking for how they differ when it comes to non-generative tasks such as embeddings.

Comment: @Daniel OK. I will update that later.

Comment: @Daniel Have I answered your question?